# R: Names of features not appearing when using table()

Tags: r

I am using the following command that returns this output:

```
> table(data$Smoke, data$Gender)
     
      female male
  no     314  334
  yes     44   33
```

Nonetheless, in the tutorial I'm watching, the instructor uses the same line of code and they get

```
      Gender
Smoke   female male
  no     314  334
  yes     44   33
```

How can I achieve this result? It's not clear from the help menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a two-column `data.frame` object to `table()`

```
table(data[c("Smoke", "Gender")])

#      Gender
# Smoke female male
#   no      29   31
#   yes     17   23
```

or use `xtabs()`:

```
xtabs( ~ Smoke + Gender, data)

#      Gender
# Smoke female male
#   no      29   31
#   yes     17   23
```

---

Although the following one also works, it looks some rude.

```
table(Smoke = data$Smoke, Gender = data$Gender)
```

---

***Data***

```
data <- data.frame(id = 1:100,
                   Smoke = sample(c("no", "yes"), 100, T),
                   Gender = sample(c("female", "male"), 100, T))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can name the vectors you pass to `table`.

```
table(Smoke = c('no','yes'), Gender = c('male','female'))

#-----
     Gender
Smoke female male
  no       0    1
  yes      1    0
```